# Bootstrap row and col explanation

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Is this valid bootstrap?

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-sm-6"></div>
 <div class="col-sm-6"></div>
 <div class="col-sm-6"></div>
 <div class="col-sm-6"></div>
 <div class="col-sm-6"></div>
</div>
```

Or do I need a new row every 12 columns?

Because right now it does not work for me to do this way. And I do not want to have a row every 12th because I need to filter my articles, and I cant do that when they are in different rows.

Comment: Bootstrap is a 12-column based framework. So yes, you can define maximum 12 columns in a row. [Here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-basic) is a good visual example

Answer (score 3):

[Bootstrap has a own Grid-System](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid), which allows you **up to 12 columns**. From the docu:

> Bootstrap includes a responsive, mobile first fluid grid system that
>   appropriately scales up to 12 columns as the device or viewport size
>   increases.

It has a reason why it is just 12, and not as many as you want to have. This article describes it perfectly well: [The Subtle Magic Behind Why the Bootstrap 3 Grid Works](http://www.helloerik.com/the-subtle-magic-behind-why-the-bootstrap-3-grid-works)

After reading this, you are perfectly ready to work with Bootstraps grid system in the way its meant to be.

Answer (score 2):

You will get a new visual row every 12 columns, but you don't need to define it with markup.

From [the documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid):

> If more than 12 columns are placed within a single row, each group of extra columns will, as one unit, wrap onto a new line.

Comment: Thanks, I thought so. 

Unfortunately that does not work for me, some columns end up not floating..... Can it be because the height of the columns over are different?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the official bootstrap docs on the [grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid). It's pretty straight forward.

Basically each row should only add up to 12. So you'd be able to fit two col-sm-6 divs within a single row (displayed as two side-by-side columns)

Answer (score 1):

**"Do I need a new row every 12 columns?"..**

Contrary to popular opinion, **it is okay** to have columns that total *more than 12 units* in a single `.row`. It simply causes the row to wrap. This is known as [column wrapping](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)..

> "If more than 12 columns are placed within a single row, each group of
> extra columns will, as one unit, wrap onto a new line"

So this...

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-sm-6"></div>
 <div class="col-sm-6"></div>
 <div class="col-sm-6"></div>
 <div class="col-sm-6"></div>
</div>
```

Is functionally the **same** as...

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-sm-6"></div>
 <div class="col-sm-6"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-sm-6"></div>
 <div class="col-sm-6"></div>
</div>
```

However, the 2nd structure would be problematic with responsive layouts (different columns on different screen sizes). Having more than 12 columns per row is a common scenario when creating `col-*` dynamically. If you're having a problem with gaps in columns of different height you can use a CSS clearfix every n-TH column like this.. http://codeply.com/go/J6cCo3xL7H

---

Related: [Where to place bootstrap row class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42500146/where-to-place-bootstrap-row-class/42500212#42500212)