# How do I get Bootstrap grid gy-5 to work?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

If I have a bootstrap grid. There is no space between the rows despite the gy-5

However if I change `class="grid"` to `class="row"` then there is space. But that doesn't make sense to me, why would I want a row of 3 rows? There's something I don't understand about how this works.

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/xpusostomos/03wqa5x6/2/

```html
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="row gy-5">
      <div class="col-md-2">
        Select:
      </div>
      
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="mapped">
                    <input id="mapped" class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="mapped"
                           (change)="change(true)"/>
                    Mapped</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-5">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="unmapped">
                    <input id="unmapped" class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="unmapped"
                           (change)="change(true)"/>
                    Unmapped</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="row gy-5">
      <div class="col-md-2">
        Show:
      </div>
      
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="summary">
                    <input id="summary" class="form-check-input" type="radio" [(ngModel)]="detail" [value]="false"
                           (change)="change(false)"/>
                    Summary</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-5">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="detail">
                    <input id="detail" class="form-check-input" type="radio" [(ngModel)]="detail" [value]="true"
                           (change)="change(false)"/>
                    Detail</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="row gy-5">
      <div class="col-md-2">
        Group:
      </div>
      
      <div class="col-md-10">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="detail">
                    <input id="mapGrouped" class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="mapGrouped"
                           [value]="true" (change)="change()"/>
                    Mapped Status</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: can you please be specific towards your question

Comment: You can start by eliminating possible errors and start writing HTML without syntax errors. Your class attribute is missing the final `"` character.

Answer (score 3):

**Gutters are for spacing between *columns* not rows.** Therefore if you want vertical spacing between the columns as they stack *vertically*, your columns should all be in the same row...

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row gy-5">
        <div class="col-md-2"> Select: </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="mapped">
                <input id="mapped" class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="mapped" (change)="change(true)" /> Mapped</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="unmapped">
                <input id="unmapped" class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="unmapped" (change)="change(true)" /> Unmapped</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2"> Show: </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="summary">
                <input id="summary" class="form-check-input" type="radio" [(ngModel)]="detail" [value]="false" (change)="change(false)" /> Summary</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="detail">
                <input id="detail" class="form-check-input" type="radio" [(ngModel)]="detail" [value]="true" (change)="change(false)" /> Detail</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2"> Group: </div>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="detail">
                <input id="mapGrouped" class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="mapGrouped" [value]="true" (change)="change()" /> Mapped Status</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://codeply.com/p/kTJczRmHhq

Understand that using more that 12 column units inside a single `.row` creates a "virtual" row which is in essence [how the responsive Bootstrap grid works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19732763/bootstrap-row-can-i-have-columns-add-up-to-more-then-12).

Note: the `grid` class is for `display:grid` which is an alternate to `row` which is for (`display:flex`) so you'd use one or the other not both.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, I should do the math so that every 12 spacing is how I get to a new row?

Comment: So what is the point of the <row> if it isn't actually a row? If you can't sensibly have more than one row, why is it designed like this?

Comment: You need to understand how the grid and breakpoints work. `row` is a flexbox container for columns, so there's no reason to repeat row in your case since the columns need to relate to each other. Columns that share the same parent 'row' may have different horizontal or vertical layout depending on the breakpoints you define in the columns. But all of this is outside the scope of the original question., and I suggest learning more about the grid. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29695531/bootstrap-row-and-col-explanation

Answer (score 0):

Inspecting your JSFiddle, it looks like `margin-top` of the rows is the problem because it delivers a negative value:

```
margin-top: calc(-1 * var(--bs-gutter-y));
```

So you have to get rid of this wrongly calculated `margin-top` and all should work fine. You could e.g. add the `m-auto` class to your rows or fix the `margin-top` in your own CSS file.

```
 <div class="container grid overflow-hidden">
    <div class="row g-5 m-auto">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            Select:
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="mapped">
                <input id="mapped" class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="mapped"
                       (change)="change(true)"/>
                Mapped</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="unmapped">
                <input id="unmapped" class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="unmapped"
                       (change)="change(true)"/>
                Unmapped</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row g-5 m-auto">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            Show:
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="summary">
                <input id="summary" class="form-check-input" type="radio" [(ngModel)]="detail" [value]="false"
                       (change)="change(false)"/>
                Summary</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="detail">
                <input id="detail" class="form-check-input" type="radio" [(ngModel)]="detail" [value]="true"
                       (change)="change(false)"/>
                Detail</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row g-5 m-auto">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            Group:
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="detail">
                <input id="mapGrouped" class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="mapGrouped"
                       [value]="true" (change)="change()"/>
                Mapped Status</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Not sure where this problem comes from. Is it maybe only in Fiddle? I never had problems with the BS grids. Alternatively you could define the [grid-gap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/spacing/#gap) to get around the problem.

Answer (score -1):

You have to mention `col` inside `row`. Please have a look at the below solution.

Reference: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/gutters/#vertical-gutters

```
<div class="container overflow-hidden">
    <div class="row gy-5">
        <div class="col-4">
            <div class="p-3">blah</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
            <div class="p-3">stuff</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
            <div class="p-3">rubbish</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you look at the fiddle I posted, the things in the rows already have class=col-md-4. I tried changing them to col-4 and that didn't help.