# bootstrap: Why div child is bigger than div parent?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have extracted a part of my web to show my problem. Why the yellow div is bigger than the black div which is his parent? How can it fit exactly in the parent? I'm new in bootstrap so I guess I'm doing something wrong

Thanks

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gsNhG.jpg)

```css
.indicador {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.indicadormedio {
  background-color: yellow;
  color: #01CB99;
  font-size: 40px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row " style=" display: table; ">

    <div class="col-sm-12 ">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <div class="row" style="background-color:red">
            <div class="col-sm-12 ">
              <div class="indicador">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-sm-12">title </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row indicadormedio">
                  <div class="col-sm-12">30</div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-sm-12">subtitle</div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: It's not bigger; `indicador` is expanding to contain `indicadormedio` like it's supposed to.

Comment: It is not bigger.. all are having same width

Comment: Rule 1 of the [bootstrap grid](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid): `Rows must be placed within a .container (fixed-width) or .container-fluid (full-width) for proper alignment and padding.`

Comment: Ron van der Heijden , I dont understand you, I have "<div class="container">" at the beggining that is what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use bootstrap classes to fix that, add `row col-sm-12` to `indicador`

**See result:**

```css
.indicador {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.indicadormedio {
  background-color: yellow;
  color: #01CB99;
  font-size: 40px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row " style=" display: table; ">

    <div class="col-sm-12 ">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <div class="row" style="background-color:red">
            <div class="col-sm-12 ">
              <div class="indicador row col-sm-12">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-sm-12">title </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row indicadormedio">
                  <div class="col-sm-12">30</div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-sm-12">subtitle</div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I don't understand why but it solved the problem. Thanks

Comment: @wakeup bootstrap has its own predefined classes and styles, so you need to use them properly :) .. if the answer helped you don't forget to accept it

Answer (score 0):

You had too many cascading divs, for which I don't see any visible purpose.
I cleaned them up and it gave [the following result](https://jsfiddle.net/2czccjzo/2/).

Which ended with the following code:

```
<div class="container" >
   <div class="row indicador"  style=" display: table; " >                              
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-sm-12" >title </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row indicadormedio">
         <div class="col-sm-12">30</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-sm-12">subtitle</div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I also route you to the [following post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19983896) to know when to use a `row` class.

Hope it helps.